# custom php forum - showing new/unread posts

Tags: php, mysql, database, forum

I have written myself a custom forum script using php.  I decided against using phpbb and others as I wanted 100% flexibility with what I was doing.

I've hit a problem though:

How do I show a user if a post is new/unread or not.

Two solutions come into mind:

1) Cookies
2) Database

I don't want to use cookies because they can be deleted by the user and the firefox side of things means they are auto deleted.  Either way, I don't want to use cookies.

The database is causing me a problem because I can't seem to get the database structure sorted in my head!  The first solution I could think of was:

- When a user loads the forums up, check the last time they loaded the forums up
- Check all the posts have been made since they last viewed the forums
- Enter those values into the database in a table with fields (user_id, post_id).
- that value is then deleted from the database when they view the post

The problems I am thinking with this is it's a huge database drain.  It seems SO inefficient.  I'm sure there are methods with arrays in fields, but I'm not really that good with arrays.

Could anyone give me an indication of a good database design for this as well as any code that has to go with it?  It's driving me crazy as I just can't think of a solution that's good and efficient with the server.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help and assistance,

James.

Comment: just add a one column could be boolean value into the post table and set to true if viewed and false if it has not been viewed yet

Comment: You can compare how the existing board-softwares do this. For example PHPBB or MyBB or the various others which code is freely available. Then choose what fits your needs.

Comment: I hesitate to post this suggestion, but I was contemplating doing the same as you, then I fell upon Vanilla forum, which is supplied really stripped down and to which you plugin the various bits you need as and when. Like hakre suggests, you could do worse than check how they are doing things even if you do not adopt it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is somehow a good question, I've never experienced this before so I could only suggest you an idea in which I have no guarantee about its correctness.

My idea basically is:

1. Create a new field, called `is_new` inside a topic table. This field contains a list of values in string form, following a certain pattern. For example: `5|6|12|110|2|45`. Each value between `|` represents a user's ID, who has read the topic.
2. Every time a user jumps into a forum, while fetching to return the list of topics, you will check if each topic is read by that user, simple by:

   - Explode the string in `is_new` using `explode('|', $row['is_new']);`
   - Now you have an array contain the values, just need to check `in_array($user['id'], $list_of_ids);`
3. If `false`, mark the topic `unread`, otherwise mark it `read` and also update that user's ID into the `is_new` list.

This approach seems less 'painful' than your original approach, since it only checks further more than ordinary, and as simultaneously as you fetch the list of topics. I think it will affect a little bit more if you have heaps of users.

**Note:** you don't have to worry about the problem of normalization since `is_new` contains multiple values, you only use it to check and update, no selection required.

In addition, alternatively, you can check the topics are new or not using time comparison. For example, if a topic lasts for 4 weeks and a user doesn't read it, then it returns old even though it's unread (it makes sense doesn't it? Just like a newspaper). I think you will be able to do this, quite easy indeed.

This approach is particularly applied by quite a few forum software, since it is quick and makes more sense. Remember that the browsers initially support you with determining read/unread topics, i.e. the color of hyperlink to the topic will be changed if it's visited. Now it turns back to the **Cookies** solution. I wouldn't worry about users deleting their cookies. This happens rarely and the users won't die just because the `read` topics turn `unread` after they delete the cookies.

Quite an open-ended topic isn't it? Hope this helps (:

Comment: @BeingSimpler, Plus One! Nice answer!

Comment: This is certainly a valid approach, but the is_new column makes me feel a bit dirty. While your point about normalization is technically true, there's still a good reason to split this information into another table: doing a string explosion, array traversal, and possible array update is excruciatingly slow compared with a JOIN. Relational databases are built to quickly and efficiently correlate this type of information, why not take advantage of it?

Comment: Justin, good point (: Yet I still think in this case it doesn't affect much since updating new ID is just like appending a new string into the current string, something like "UPDATE topic SET is_new = CONCAT(is_new,'|$id')". As I said, this field acts as a independent storage for matching values, it doesn't need to be related to any other fields and doesn't require any specific selection. Your approach is correct, it even sounds true to me, but it's different from my thought and approach. Mine takes possibly 2 lines of code, and doesn't slow down that much compared to using raw RDB apporach.

Comment: many thanks for the reply.  Although I do agree with Justin on this case, I currently have a relatively small number of people using the website anyway (I think it's something like 10-20k page views a day) and less of those will be on the forums.

I will stick with that method for the moment I think and look into the other method when my website starts expanding more.  I have a very tight development schedule so having something that's slightly less efficient but get's it done in a fraction of the time is highly important.

Many thanks to all who have posted in this question.  Thank you.

Comment: I have successfully added that functionality to the website and it works beautifully.  I decided to add a "new posts" button so people click that and see new posts rather than adding any more drain on the server by highlighting individual posts in the listings. Many thanks again for your help

Comment: That's good (: Hope you are enjoying what you've done, best part of programming!

Answer (score 5):

A lot of the larger forum software uses a tracking table to keep up with who has read what, something like this (heavily simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE topic_tracking (
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    topic_id INT NOT NULL,
    last_visit DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, topic_id)
)
```

You then use a join on this table to check if a post you're displaying is read or not. Since you'll be paging your threads, this should generate relatively few additional queries (depending on how many posts you show per page).

When a user visits the thread, update this tracking table with the timestamp of their visit. Then when displaying your thread links, check this table to see if their last_visit is earlier than the last post in the thread. This also lets you show "updated" threads, not just "new" ones.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, good question.

I will toss my two cents in on how I would handle this, it may not be the most efficient solution, but here goes:

I would use a database to solve this problem.  If possible create a field in the database that attaches to a specific user.  Inside this field (or column or table if you prefer) store a list of "viewed" articles by the article ID.

When rendering the page for the user, retrieve their list of "viewed" articles and a list of all the article ID's available.

Loop through your Article/forum/topic result set and see if that ID matches any of the "viewed" ID's.  For every Article/forum/topic entry that does not have a corresponding "viewed" match, then to that user it would be a "new" article.

This is processor/database/network intensive and requires a look up to the database each time a page is loaded that contains article references.  Although with a bit of clever query design I think you could offload this kind of operation almost entirely to the database.

Also another potential solution using the database, would be that when a user first logs into the site, you fetch a list of read articles/forums at that first load point and add it to a cookie or session, this way you only hit the database for that list once (on first load), and store it in a session/cookie/hidden field, so that in subsequent requests you would only have to go to that cookie/session/hidden field instead of performing a Db look up each and every time the user views a page with a list of articles/forums/topics.  Each time the user clicks a link, capture and store it in the database, and also store that article/forum ID in your cookie/session/hidden field.  Once again, perhaps not the most efficient method, but with some good old fashioned gumption I am sure you will prevail.   :)

Best of Luck to you!

H

Answer (score 0):

A session would be a good place to store this. I'd imagine you'd only want to store the data for the last "n" threads that a user looks at or only for threads in the last "n" days.

As someone has suggested in one of the comments it's worth looking at some of the existing forums out there and see how they implement this.

While I think it's a great learning opportunity to write your own forum software in terms of efficiency of building it yourself I think that you're re-inventing the wheel somewhat.

Comment: The problem with a session is that I would have to use an array to do that wouldn't I?  Then, what happens if the person closes the browser?  They would still have new posts that were not read previously and they won't be shown as "new" anymore, even though they are.

The advantage of using the database is that the post will always stay as "new" even if they close the browser because the value stays "unread" until they read it.

I agree that I am "reinventing the wheel" so to speak, but I was fed up of trying to modify other people's coding to make it work for me.  It just wasn't working..

Comment: Not being able to work with arrays is going to really limit your ability to build functionality. I'd really suggest investing some time learning about it. There are a bunch of good tutorials out there, just search for "php arrays" on Google

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Regarding the point I made about the session though, what would you suggest for that?  If they close the browser half way through viewing new posts, what happens if they come back at a later date?  

I will attempt to load up the phpbb forum code now and see how they show the new posts.  I'm not sure if it'll be possible to find it.. but I will try! :)

If you have any thoughts on the database side, be sure to let me know :) thank you

Comment: @James, James C is correct in saying that not being able to effectively use Arrays is really going to limit your programming ability.  As for thoughts on how to handle the marking of posts as new or not, list your articles on a page and provide a anchor link to each article, then bind a javascript/jQuery function to that links "onclick" event that does a AJAX call back to the server to notify the server that the user just clicked on an article link and to record that articles ID number. The next time the user looks at the page, the value stored in the database indicates it has been viewed.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to save the last post id of each topic a specific user has seen in the database:

```
user_id   topic_id   post_id
1         2          3
```

So, here you know that user 1 visited the third post in the second topic, but didn't look at the first topic at all.

To check if the user has new/unread topics you can first check for topic_id's which are not in this table for that user. To check if known topics have new messages you can compare the post_id with the last post_id of each topic. If they are not equal, there are new messages.